# Задержка перед выполнением слушателя. Android

Tags: java, android, search, listener

Необходимо немного оптимизировать запросы в приложении Android и разгрузить процессор.

Есть строка поиска со своим слушателем событий на изменение текста в данной строке. Необходимо произвести действие1 (поиск в листе), если данные в строке не менялись более 3 секунд. Действие1 должно производится не при каждом изменении значения строки поиска с задержкой 3 сек, а только один раз, после того как строка изменялась и осталась в таком виде более 3 секунд.

Comment: Thread.sleep(3000);

Comment: Не вариант. Так Вы усыпите главный поток, не можно продолжать вводить текст в строку поиска. Нужно либо чтоб потоки заменялись динамически и там ставить паузы (но как это сделать?) либо ХЗ как ещё.

Comment: создайте отдельный поток, поспите 3 сек и потом делайте то что надо

Comment: уже пробовал. Кидает эксепшн через время + выполняется команда при каждом измении значения ячейки (каждый раз создается новый поток, либо эксепшн о том что поток уже существует)

Comment: Создаете переменную Thread, куда будете класть созданный поток. Перед тем как положить, проверяйте состояние потока, если null создаете и используете. Если Runnable то ничего не делаете. Если Terminate - создаете новый

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) - при действии1 с помощью методов `remove*` удаляем не успевшие выполниться и `send*Delayed / postDelayed` ставим задачу

Answer (score 0):

Можно как-то так c помощью `rxJava` и `RxBinding`:

Заводим в активити переменные:

```
long time;
private static final int INTERVAL = 3;
```

Потом берём `EditText` и подписываемся на изменения ввода в нём, каждый раз обновляем переменную `time` и начинаем ждать `n` секунд. После ожидания проверяем, что `текущее время - time` больше заданного интервала и только в этом случае что-то делаем.

```
RxTextView.textChanges(editText)
    .doOnEach(text -> time = System.currentTimeMillis())
    .flatMap(text -> Observable.timer(INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS).flatMap(v -> Observable.just(text)))
    .observeOn(Schedullers.io())
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedullers.mainTread())
    .filter(text -> (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) >= INTERVAL)
    .subscribe(text - > Log.d("TAG", text));
```